# Two selects based on one select in on query

Tags: sql, postgresql

Can I do one select and then do different selects on the result in one query?

Now I want to do something like that (which is not working)

```
select 
    (select count(*), sum(amount) from view where amount > 5), 
    (select count(*), sum(amount) from view where amount < 5) 
from 
    (select id, amount from warehouse where createDate = '2019-01-01') as view;
```

I don't want to select view and then select some data with additional filtering based on the view.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use conditional aggregation:

```
select count(*), 
       sum(amount) filter (where waga > 5),
       sum(amount) filter (where amount < 5) 
from warehouse 
where createdate = date '2019-01-01'
```

Comment: Is this query has a fine performance? I don't want to scan whole table two times.
Also I need to count(*) and sum by each filter\

Comment: @ByeBye: Yes, this query should have optimal performance. If there are many dates in the table, you should have an index on `createDate`.

Comment: @ByeBye: this will only query the table once. If there is an index on `createdate` and that limits the number of rows substantially, it will use the index

Answer (score 1):

About the general syntax question you could use WITH clause:

```
with v as
(
 select id, amount from warehouse where createDate = '2019-01-01'
)
select * from
(
    (select count(*), sum(amount) from v where waga > 5) as count1, 
    (select count(*), sum(amount) from v where amount < 5) as count2
);
```

(I don't mean it will be faster; it's just a way to use an "inline" view).